# Solving partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, boundary-conditions, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am new to mathematica and I want to solve the following pde. I have two boundary conditions and one initial condition.[image]

I have tried the following code but the output is not the solution and it's just a simplified version of the equation. This is the code that I've tried:

```
pde = D[T[r, t], t]/a == D[r^2 D[T[r, t], r], r]
ic = {T[r, 0] == 0, k*A*D[T[r, t], r] == Q*HeavisideTheta[tao - t] /. r -> 0.5 dp,T[Infinity, t] == 0}
DSolveValue[{pde, ic}, T[r, t], {r, t}]
```

I have used other functions like NDSolve, but nothing seems to work. I would appreciate it if you could tell me what is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: You cannot use `Infinity` as a boundary condition.  However, even with a finite quantity specified, `DSolve` may not be able to solve this problem.  `NDSolve` should work (with `Infinity` replaced by some large, but not too large, number.  However, it is difficult for the reader to say more without seeing your code for `NDSolve`.

Comment: thank you @bbgodfrey . I am using ' NDSolve[{pde, ic}, T, {r, 0.5, 500}, {t, 0, 3}] '. and now I encounter errors 1.Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent. 2. Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t==0. I am sure that the physics are accurate and there must be another reason.

Comment: Be sure you assign numerical values to the various constants in `pde` and `ic`.  Otherwise, `NDSolve` will fail with the second error you listed.  If the code still does not work, I suggest that you ask a new question involving `NDSolve` instead of `DSolve`.